# Delete ranges of id's

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this huge SQL query which I would like to reduce:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE id in (754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 765,
766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794);
```

I tried:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE id => 754 AND id <= 759
AND id => 795 AND id <= 799
AND id => 765 AND id <= 794;
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "=>"
Position: 42
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Those conditions are self-contradictory so no row will be deleted. There's no number that's less than 759 *and* greater than 795

Comment: The "greater than or equal" operator is `>=` not `=>` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
DELETE
FROM users
WHERE 
   id between 754 and 759
OR id between 765 and 799
```

Answer (score 1):

use `>=` operator

example

```
delete from users where id >= 754
```

Comment: operand, not statement.